# REST-сервис - в JSON-ответе не все поля исходного обьекта

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Всем привет. Возникла не совсем понятная мне ситуация: есть сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trCompany")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransportCompany implements Serializable, Storable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1000000005645644L;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @JsonView(Views.User.class)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @JsonView(Views.User.class)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 150)
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    @JsonView(Views.User.class)
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true)
    private String phone;

    ...

    @Transient
    @JsonView(Views.User.class)
    private Collection<Orders> orderCollection;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return String.format("%d, %s, %s, %s;",
            id, name, phone, orderCollection);
    }

    ...

}
```

Есть дао и сервисы, и контроллер вида

```
@RestController
public class TransportCompanyController {
.....
    @JsonView(Views.User.class)
    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/t/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getAll(){

        List<TransportCompany> transportCompanyList = transportCompanyService.getAll();

        System.out.println("TR-COMP: " + transportCompanyList.get(0).toString());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(transportCompanyList);
    }
...
}
```

И это все завернуто в spring-boot. В общем проблема в получаемом JSON-ответе, он он имеет вид:

```
[{"name":"Новая почта","phone":"+380671111111"},{...},{...}]
```

а мне, ну очень, при-очень, нужно что бы ответ имел такой вид, с ***ID***:

```
 [{"id":"1","name":"Новая почта","phone":"+380671111111"},{...},{...}]
```

В общем что то с JSON-представлением не то, хотя работа с аналогично описанными сущностями для других обьектов, но подобных, обектов и их контроллеров соответсвенно - работают нормально, т.е. ответ приходит с ID - как полагается ...
Заранее благодарен за ответ!
*PS/ На всякий случай. Внутри контроллера есть System.out, там все хорошо ID - присудствует.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай так и ваш id отобразится в json:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trCompany")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransportCompany implements Serializable, Storable {

   @JsonView(Views.User.class)
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   @id
   Long id;

   @JsonProperty("id")
   public Long getId() { return id; }

   public void setId(Long id){ this.id = id; }
}
```

Comment: Если честно - то не помогло. **_Но спасибо огромное_**, тк благодаря Вам я _**нашел свою дебильную ошибку**_. Оказалось что мой геттер был с NULL )). а System.out срабатывал тк там toString(). В общем работало потому что я нигде более не использовал геттер...
PS/ мне нужно быть внимательнее, блин... Спасибо Вам. Отсюда можно вынести урок, что даже после авто-генерации сеттеров и геттеров, их стоит = ПРОВЕРИТЬ, блин ...

Comment: Используй Lombok и не заморачивайся с геттерами